# Can't get items from ListView

Tags: android

I have this class but I cannot get the ListView Items without the click listener ... I simply want to update the color of the text onResume ...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.overlay_options, FishSpecie.getFishSpecies()));

    mList = getListView();
    mList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Boolean status = doClick(((TextView) arg1).getText());
            if(status == true)
            {
                ((TextView) arg1).setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) arg1).getText() + " Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                ((TextView) arg1).setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) arg1).getText() + " Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }               
        }           
    });

    // Create all the overlay check boxes and labels
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    updateList();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    updateList();
}

protected void updateList() {
    mList = getListView();

    for (int i = 0; i < mList.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View v = mList.getChildAt(i);
        TextView tx = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.layout.overlay_options);
        if(FishSpecie.isFishSpecieEnabled(tx.getId()) == true) {
            // Change color of list item
            tx.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else
        {
            tx.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        }
    }
}
```

View v = mList.getChildAt(i); this never finds the child

To clarify mList.getChildCount() always returns 0

I think i've nearly fixed it but I can't understand why the color change doesn't take affect ... Below is the new code for the update function

```
protected void updateList() {

    for (int i = 0; i < mArray.getCount();i++) {
        //TextView v = (TextView)(findViewById((int) mArray.getItemId(i)));
        TextView v = (TextView) mArray.getView(i, null , null);
        String text = (String) v.getText();
        if(FishSpecie.isFishSpecieEnabled(i) == true) {
            // Change color of list item
            v.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else
        {
            v.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After calling 'View v = mList.getChildAt(i);', is v null? If not, what is its value? @Alex Gitelman is right - 'R.layout.overlay_options' isn't the right type of resource to be searching for.

Comment: After onResume, is your list still visible? If not, you may need to re-bind it to the adapter. If it is visible, the problem may be in the getListView() method.

Comment: It doesn't matter at this point since that line of code isn't executed. I clarified a bit in the post at the end, the getChildCount is always 0.

Comment: Yes on resume its properly displayed except that the colors don't get updated ... that's the issue I'm trying to resolve. Yes the getListView() doesn't contain the views which is the base problem. However, I'm not sure what the proper way to get the views is after creating them with listAdapter.

Comment: I updated my answer. You probably need to customize your adapter to achieve your goal of highlighting.

Comment: I've updated the code, see OP, but It won't update the colors when I setTextColor ..

Answer (score 1):

When searching for text view you probably want `R.id.overlay_options` not `R.layout.overlay_options`.

---

Update

Not sure why you get 0 child count but your approach is, probably, not going to work as those views are reused for diffeent items. Better approach may be to customize `getView` method on adapter to show proper color.

Comment: This is the xml file ...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="15dp">
</TextView>

Comment: you have to specify @+id for your TextView and then use it for lookup.

Comment: It never even gets there ... 

To clarify mList.getChildCount() always returns 0

Comment: thanks for clarifying that you get 0 children. It was not clear at first.